# Is there a GitHub issue webhook?

Tags: github, githooks

So I am unclear on GH docs as to whether their webhook supports issue notification. It sounds like it support webhooks. However when I set up test endpoints nothing comes, even when I test payload.

I am using ultrahook.com as well as requestb.in to catch requests but nothing comes.

Are github webhooks even working? Has anyone got it to work?

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/post-receive-hooks should work without a problem http://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/

Comment: As far as I can tell they are not working or delayed by hours. I've tried both above services and they receive nothing - but tests using Hurl show up. I may be missing something but not sure what. I enter a requestb.in url in my repo webhook field, press test and would expect something but nada.

Comment: OK - seems that webhooks dont work unless you have code - I was testing a test repo which doesnt work. And I dont think issues work with webhooks - waiting on a confirm from support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [new WebHooks GUI (February 2014)](https://github.com/blog/1778-webhooks-level-up) makes it very clear about its Issue event support:

[image: https://f.cloud.github.com/assets/2501/2054474/0085e64a-8ab6-11e3-8f0e-cee61e7d4ede.png]

And even if you don't have code yet, you can at least test that your webhook is in place with a new [ping event](http://developer.github.com/webhooks/#ping-event).

Comment: @VonC Any idea if there's some hook to listen for changes on a PR description/title?

Comment: @dimirc no, not from what I can see of the list of events monitored. Maybe the GitHub support could say more about this.